# MongoDB schema / object to a C# Object mapping generator?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

How can I take the Mongo schema or example object and generate a C# Object automatically?

From:

```
{
 bsonType: "object",
 title: "Movie object",
 required: [ "title", "year", "runtime", "plot", "cast" ],
 properties: {
    title: {
       bsonType: "string",
       description: "'name' must be a string and is required"
    },
    year: {
       bsonType: "int",
       minimum: 2017,
       maximum: 3017,
       description: "'year' must be an integer in [ 2017, 3017 ] and is required"
    },
    runtime: {
       bsonType: "int",
       minimum: 1,       
       description: "'runtime' must be an positive integer and is required"
    },
    plot: {
       bsonType: "string",
       description: "'plot' must be a string and is required"
    },
    caat: {
        bsonType: "array"
        description: "'cast' is an array of strings"
    }
 }
}
```

To:

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;

[BsonIgnoreExtraElements] 
public class Movie {

    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; } = null!;

    [BsonElement("year")]
    public int Year { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("runtime")]
    public int Runtime { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("plot")]
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull]
    public string Plot { get; set; } = null!;

    [BsonElement("cast")]
    [BsonIgnoreIfNull] 
    public List<string> Cast { get; set; } = null!;

}
```

Comment: i doubt such logic exists

Comment: A workaround would be to get a JSON from the BSON and convert it to a C#-Class via online-tools. But the annotations still need to be changed.